# Get contents of HttpResponseRedirect in Django

Tags: python, django, session, authentication, httpresponse

If I'm logged in and I'm at a specific view, how would I make the contents of another protected (authentication required) path  on the same Django site available to this specific view?

I've attempted to manually construct a urllib2 opener and passing the logged in user's sessionid:

```
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
session_id = request.COOKIES.get('sessionid')
opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie', 'sessionid={0}'.format(session_id)))
html = opener.open(redirect_url).read()
```

The above doesn't work, the content of the page is the login page because it doesn't consider the user to be logged in. Perhaps I'm missing some more header info?

I've also attempted grabbing the contents of a HttpResponseRedirect, but since the response is not rendered, the contents are empty:

```
h = HttpResponseRedirect("http://{0}/{1}".format(domain, protected_path))
h.content # this is empty
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just call the specific view referring to this second url inside view and assing its returned value to some variable?

Comment: Or if necessary abstract out the shared behavior into a helper that both views can call.

Comment: prometh07: I can't return the second view as a response. I need to log the user out after the second view's rendered response is available. The first view is a public proxy that temporarily logs in a user in, grabs protected content from the second view, logs the user out, and returns the protected content in a new response. The proxy is being used to forward content to an online PDF generator, which would not have access to protected paths.